# (Why) does git super-repository keep anything more than a pointer to submodules?

Tags: git, version-control, dependencies, version, versioning

When using git submodules, why is a `project/.git/modules/<submodule name>/` folder added, containing what seems to be a (copy of the submodules?) repository?

**UPDATE**

Ok so this is my sense of it (with everything being local in my case, I'm denoting where it wouldn't have to be)

`absolute/path/to/actual/<submodule>/.git` ~= **(local) remote repo**
`project/.git/modules/<submodule>/` ~= **local clone repo**
`project/path/to/<submodule>/` = **local checkout** of **local clone repo**

Changes to **local checkout** are diffed with **local clone repo**, which again can be (but isn't automatically) synced with **(local) remote repo**.*

The fact that **(local) remote repo** is checked into `/absolute/path/to/actual/<submodule>` (or anywhere else) is just incidental. There's no (direct) relationship between it and `project` at all.

*: I.e. to update **(local) remote repo** so any `project X` could incorporate interusable changes made to submodule in `project`.

Meaning that for **local clone repo** I could have many unpushed changes (branches, etc) with and that are local to `project`. Some of which I won't ever want to push to **(local) remote repo**, because they're not interusable between projects.

Comment: If that's a copy, can you tell me where is the original repository? Hint: if you can't, that's because that's not a copy ;-)

Comment: The submodule repository? It's at a local path being referenced in at least both (seems redundant too?) `project/.gitmodules` and `project/.git/config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because a a git submodule is a way of embedding the working directory of another git repository into the working directory of your project with all the code management capabilities that git provies.

The path `project/.git/modules/<submodule name>` is the actual git repository (equivalent to `project/.git` of a "standard" clone) for the submodule while `project/path/to/<submodule name>` is the working directory. The reason for this is it lets you manipulate the contents of `project/path/to/<submodule name>` as a full git repository (you can checkout new commits, rather than having to somehow copy them from some other location).

Submodules, essentially, do a clone along the lines of `git clone --separate-git-dir=.git/modules/<submodule name> <submodule origin> path/to/<submodule name>` from your project's root.

It's worth noting that this is only in a cloned (non-bare) version of a repository. The actual repository itself *does* simply contain a reference to the submodule (path, origin, and commit).

Comment: Thanks I think this really increased my understanding of submodules. Accepted and updated the original post. Feel free to comment if I missed something!